# How to audit system user logon , log off , database shutdown and startup (System Level Auditing)

Tags: oracle, plsql, audit-trail

How to enable a system or database level auditing in Oracle using SQL commands or rather in SQLPlus. Something to do with table views such as dba_audit_session. Overall I'm looking for SQL statement that audits the logon or attempts the logon of users and database startup time or shutdown.

Comment: _"using SQL commands or rather in SQLPlus."_ Well, if you are in sqlplus, you should be issuing SQL commands (and possibly sqlplus directives).  Your statement sounds like you think its either SQL commands or sqlplus.   Have you actually looked up the AUDIT statement in the SQL Language Reference for your unnamed version of orcle?  If not, then do so now.  If you have, then what parts are you having difficulty understanding?

Comment: Well yes I did but I’m not a 100% sure if I’m doing it right I used AUDIT SESSION

Comment: _"Well yes I did but I’m not a 100% sure if I’m doing it right"_   Since you didn't _show_ us exactly what you did, we have no way of evaluating if you are doing it right.  What does your own testing show?

Answer (score 0):

To audit logins and logouts create LOGON and LOGOFF triggers that populate a regular history table. I myself prefer it. It's far simpler:

```
create table log_trail (name varchar2(30), time date, action varchar2(10));

create or replace trigger tr_logon
after logon on database
begin
insert into log_trail values (user, sysdate, 'LOGON');
commit;
end tr_logon;

create or replace trigger tr_logoff
before logoff on database
begin
insert into log_trail values (user, sysdate, 'LOGOFF');
commit;
end tr_logon;
```

Notes:

- Beware of logon triggers. If they are not working, you may not logon to Oracle.
- You must have the CREATE (ANY) TRIGGER and ADMINISTER DATABASE TRIGGER privileges to implement DATABASE triggers

Comment: Did my solution work?